# Python pass vs. continue

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, couldn't figure out the following syntax,

```
item = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for element in item:
      if not element:
          pass
      print(element)
```

this gives me all of these element, it make sense as Pass is skip this step to next one

however if I use continue I will get the following

```
item = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for element in item:
      if not element:
          continue
      print(element)
```

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Can someone tell me why don't I get '0'? Is 0 not in the list?

Comment: `continue` skips the rest of the loop body and *continues* with the next iteration of the loop. `pass` does nothing at all.

Comment: apart from the `pass/continue` conundrum which has been answered, what are you trying to achieve? There may be better ways to scan the list and produce the desired output (e.g. `filter(None, item)`)

Answer (score 7):

`continue` skips the statements after it, whereas `pass` do nothing like that. Actually `pass` do nothing at all, useful to handle some syntax error like:

```
 if(somecondition):  #no line after ":" will give you a syntax error
```

You can handle it by:

```
 if(somecondition):
     pass   # Do nothing, simply jumps to next line
```

Demo:

```
while(True):
    continue
    print "You won't see this"
```

This will skip the `print` statement and print nothing.

```
while(True):
    pass
    print "You will see this"
```

This will keep printing `You will see this`

Answer (score 3):

- "pass" just means "no operation". it does not do anything.
- "continue" breaks a loop and jumps to the next iteration of the loop
- "not 0" is True, so your "if not element" with element=0 triggers the continue instruction, and directly jumps to next iteration: element = 1

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is a no-op. It does nothing. So when `not element` is true, Python does nothing and just goes on. You may as well leave out the whole `if` test for the difference that is being made here.

`continue` means: skip the rest of the loop body and go to the next iteration. So when `not element` is true, Python skips the rest of the loop (the `print(element)` line), and *continues* with the next iteration.

`not element` is true when `element` is 0; see [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).